# FIND_IN_SET and sort by the number of matches

Tags: php, mysql

I create query as below. It is working perfectly fine:

```
$get_products = "SELECT P.*, C.`category_name`,
                 GROUP_CONCAT(`category_name` SEPARATOR ', ') 
                 AS cat 
                 FROM `products` P 
                 NATURAL JOIN `categories` C 
                 NATURAL JOIN `product_to_categories` 
                 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`category_name`, '$selected_categories') 
                    AND `product_price` 
                    BETWEEN '$price_min' 
                    AND '$price_max' 
                 GROUP BY `product_name` 
                 ORDER BY 1 DESC";
```

So if I have products i.e.:

**APPLE** belonging to the categories: **FRUIT**, **GREEN**, **ROUND**
**WHEEL** belonging to the categories: **MACHINES**, **BLACK**, **ROUND**
**BANANA** belonging to the categories: **FRUIT**, **YELLOW**, **CUBOID**
**PHONE** belonging to the categories: **ELECTRONICS**, **BLACK**, **CUBOID**

and select categories: **FRUIT** and **ROUND**
I will receive: 
**APPLE** (2 matches: FRUIT and ROUND), **WHEEL** (1 match: ROUND) and **BANANA** (1 match: FRUIT)

Now I am trying to sort it by number of matches (APPLE with 2 matches on first place, BANANA with 1 match on 2nd place and so on...)

Is there any way I could get this?

Comment: Please introduce line breaks when you post code, we don’t want to have to scroll several miles sideways to see your full code.

Comment: @CBroe, sorry - mea culpa. Corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to `order by` category name within the group.

```
$get_products = "SELECT P.*, C.`category_name`, GROUP_CONCAT(`category_name` SEPARATOR ', ') AS cat FROM `products` P NATURAL JOIN `categories` C NATURAL JOIN `product_to_categories` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`category_name`, '$selected_categories') AND `product_price` BETWEEN '$price_min' AND '$price_max' GROUP BY `product_name` 
                 ORDER BY count(C.`category_name`) DESC";
```